# Adding items to a html list from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to add items from my array in javascript into my html list. I have gotten it where the array displays but my entire array displays in one bullet point on my list instead of each item on their own bullet points.

eg

```
•Sugar,Milk,Bread,Apples
```

instead of

```
•Sugar
•Milk
•Bread
•Apples
```

```js
let myArray = ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread", "Apples"]

arrayList = (arr) => {
    let list1 = document.querySelector("#itemList");
    let myListItems = document.createElement("li");
    myListItems.textContent = arr;
    list1.appendChild(myListItems)
}

arrayList(myArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're getting the text of *all* the array elements and putting them in to a single `li`.

To fix the problem you need to loop through the array, creating a new `li` for each item within it:

```js
let myArray = ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread", "Apples"];
let list1 = document.querySelector("#itemList");

arrayList = (arr) => {
  let items = arr.forEach(item => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = item;
    list1.appendChild(li)
  });
}

arrayList(myArray)
```

```html
<ul id="itemList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the array:

```html
<html>
<body>
<ul id="itemList">
</ul>
</body>
<script>
const myArray = ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread", "Apples"]

createLiAndAppend = (arr, listId) => {
    const list1 = document.getElementById(listId);
    const myListItems = document.createElement("li");
    myListItems.textContent = arr;
    list1.appendChild(myListItems);
}

myArray.forEach(m => createLiAndAppend(m, "itemList"));
</script>
</html>
```